# This query worked perfectly, but now it is giving me a Syntax Error

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqlcommand

This is my code and it is giving me error that:

```
incorrent syntax near @Semester
```

My query is as follows:

```
string query = @"insert into Course_teacher(CourseName , TeacherName , Semester) 
                           values(@CourseName , @TeacherName ,@Semester";
db.OpenConnection();
db.com = new SqlCommand(query, db.con);
db.com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CourseName", textBox_CourseName.Text.Trim());
db.com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TeacherName", textBox_TeacherName.Text.Trim());
db.com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Semester", comboBox_Semester.SelectedValue);
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: its giving me error that Incorrect syntax near @Semester

Comment: comboBox_Semester.SelectedValue.ToString().  It is better to use Add than AddWithValue.  With Add method you can specify data type, while using AddWithValue you are letting the compiler guess you data type.  Guessing can cause errors or wrong data getting added to the database.

Answer (score 2):

```
values(@CourseName , @TeacherName ,@Semester";
```

Replace with:

```
values(@CourseName , @TeacherName ,@Semester)";
```

Comment: Thankyou so much.. i made such a stupid mistake.. thanks again

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to put `)` in the end of your query, so you used `values(` instead of correct `values()`, therefore it generates syntax error for SQL query.

This code for `query` should works fine:

```
string query = @"insert into Course_teacher(CourseName , TeacherName , Semester) 
                           values(@CourseName , @TeacherName ,@Semester)";
```